# SQLite alter table with result from select statement

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I am trying to execute this statement in mozilla sqlite add-on

```
alter table (select tbl_name from sqlite_master where rowid=1) add  GUID varchar
```

But this runs into error :

SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: alter table (select tbl_name from sqlite_master where rowid=1) add  GUID varchar [ near "(": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

the statement :select tbl_name from sqlite_master where rowid=1 works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that: in SQL, table names and column names must be identifiers embedded in the SQL string itself. They cannot come from values that you query, or even in a query parameter.

You need to select the table name, make the `alter table` statement, and then execute it separately.

Comment: is it possible to use a variable to hold the queried data?

Comment: @zahreelay I am not sure if SQLite allows storing the results in a variable, but even if it did, you wouldn't be able to use the value of that variable in an `alter` statement. The name of the table must be an identifier, not an expression that produces a string which can be used as an identifier.

Comment: Thanks. I have 300 tables in a Db, I need to add a column to each one of them. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @zahreelay Run a query `select 'alter table '||tbl_name||' add  GUID varchar' from sqlite_master`, copy the rows it returns in a text editor, and execute the resultant commands in SQLite (you may need to add semicolons).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77865225/can-i-prepare-alter-table-rename-to-in-sqlite