# SQLite: How to add a column to all the tables in the database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, alter-table

I am quite new to SQLite (SQL overall). I created a database and created multiple tables in it and suddenly realized I had forgot to add a column to them. Now I have 280 tables  having distinct names without a column. I have tried adding * and combining with SELECT but it gives an error. How can I accomplish it?

my code:

```
ALTER TABLE "MYBUS.*" ADD COLUMN STOPID int null;
```

Comment: what actually you trying ??

Comment: Why do you need 280 tables?

Comment: Sounds like a database design nightmare - let me guess: You need to add a new table every time there is a new "bus".

Comment: i am building a bus routes database for my city. I created those tables with stop name, stop location, bus id  as columns, but forgot to add stop id.

Comment: What is the information in the second part of the table name?

Comment: MYBUS is my database name. I used * to get all tables but cant get them.

Comment: I don't think sqlite would support this. Why not write a quick php or python script that will create your 280 SQL queries which you can then copy and paste in your sqlite client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 3 hours issue finally solved.
After searching for sometime, I stumbled upon this answer
[SQlite alter table with result from select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235526/sqlite-alter-table-with-result-from-select-statement)

I ran the code:`select 'alter table '||tbl_name||' add STOPID int null' from sqlite_master`

It returned all the 280 SQL queries needed but with quotation marks, so I took the clue from [this.lau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561309/this-lau) and created a python regex script and ran it. Worked like a charm and within 10 lines of code I was able to add a column to all my 280 tables.

Answer (score -1):

See this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160145/add-columns-to-all-tables-in-a-database-if-the-columns-dont-exist

Even though it applies to SQL Server, this should help you in getting started.

Ensure that you perform a check on the column name before adding it to a table.

Comment: Tried with errors. being a noob I don't know what to replace by what.