# Can I prepare "ALTER TABLE ? RENAME TO ?;" in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, prepared-statement, alter-table

When trying to prepare statement `ALTER TABLE ? RENAME TO ?;` in SQLite 3.7.17 via DBD-SQLite-1.40 in order to upgrade the schema being used, I got an error message:

> near "?": syntax error

So I wonder whether using `$dbh->prepare()` the reason for the "syntax" error?

Comment: You can only use placeholders for _data_, not for _structural_ parts of any statement. Table names are part of the _structure_ of your statements.

Comment: You can't do that. Parameters are for *values*, not object names. A parameterized SQL query is equivalent to a function in a strongly typed language. The entire query is already compiled into an execution plan and individual values are passed as parameters to that execution plan.

Comment: So would "preparing DDL commands is not supported" be a better error message? The idea to "prepare" the statement was that similar statements would be executed with different parameters.

Comment: No it's not. This isn't even about *preparing* statements, that's just the term used by some drivers or languages, it's about creating queries with run-time parameters. Besides, there's nothing to precompile in `ALTER TABLE Products ...`.

Comment: When you execute `SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 on .... Where ID=456` the database *compiles* this SQL query into an execution plan based on the existence of indexes and data statistics. If an index is available, the server may use an index seek operation to find matches. If all values are the same though, the server may decide to just scan the entire table. There are different JOIN strategies too, eg looping over both tables, or sorting both on the key and merging the rows. With a parameterized query/prepared statement, the query is compiled into an execution plan once and reused.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But internally database tables are in some kind of system tables that may have indexes, too. I mean even if there is no performance gain, SQLite could allow it for a unified interface. Also I think that using prepared statements adds a safety barrier against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot:

1. Placeholders cannot be used for table and column names
2. Commands manipulating the table structure (DDL) cannot be prepared.